# Understanding a derivative-based proof of $\sin(x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, trigonometry

I'm looking at one proof for $\sin(x+y)$. The process is clear but for one early step kind of confuses me.

> Let $f$, $g$ be differentiable functions satisfying $f' = g$ and $g' = −f$.
> Now, the derivatives of $f\,\sin+g\,\cos$ and $f\,\cos−g\,\sin$ vanish; hence, $$f(x)\sin x + g(x)\cos x = g(0)$$
> and
> $$f(x)\cos x − g(x)\sin x = f(0)$$

How do $g(0)$ and $f(0)$ appear?

I only know it should be a constant, but how it has anything to do with $f$ or $g$?

Comment: I suddenly realize that makes $x=0$ to both functions and the result follows.

Comment: Good job! Want me to delete my answer which I wrote before seeing this?

Comment: @Laura It's good to have questions as answered anyway / not answer them in comments.

Comment: @FShrike okay dokay! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the derivative of $f(x)\sin(x) + g(x)\cos(x)$ is $0$, the function is constant. Since we know what $\sin(0)$ and $\cos(0)$ are, we may then evaluate it at $x=0$ to obtain $$f(0)\sin(0) + g(0)\cos(0) = f(0)\cdot0 + g(0)\cdot1 = g(0),$$ which is then the function's value at any $x$. The same logic applies to $f(x)\cos(x) - g(x)\sin(x)$, which we evaluate at $x=0$ to get just $f(0)$.